# Bicycles Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion

> ## Update
>
> We mailed out the packages last week, but unfortunately our warehouse only included one water bottle instead of two. They'll send out the 2nd bottle in a separate package ASAP.

---

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Bicycles Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Bicycles Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Two Bicycles Stack Exchange water bottles from [specialized.com](http://specializedwaterbottles.com/purist/)
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: bicycles.stackexchange.com t-shirt]

### The sticker

[image: bicycles.stackexchange.com sticker]

### The water bottle

[image: bicycles.stackexchange.com water bottle]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: WOO! That even looks like a T-shirt I'd actually wear pretty regularly. What size are the stickers?

Comment: @freiheit I believe they're 2.5" x 2.5".

Comment: That is amazing!  I love it.  One suggestion: a pair of water bottles, not just one. It's a bit OCD of me, but I usually don't use a mismatched set on my bike. If not possible, then, I'll use it at work. Thanks SO much. This is very cool.

Comment: @zenbike On my bike that this bottle matches, I've paired it with a regular blue Specialized Purist bottle. Color matches perfectly, just different graphics. Also different heights, but that works well on that particular bike.

Comment: Ah.  Unfortunately, nothing in the UAE for Specialized.

Comment: HOLY YES. I'm the last user on page 2 as of this post. WOO!

Comment: @meagar close call! Happy Holidays!

Comment: Holy crap, happy Christmahaunakwanzaka to you too, bicycles.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I really like the way the water bottles look, but it took me a while to figure out what the four white spots  on the shirt were. Not to complain--I'm very happy. :) Thanks for the nice gesture.

Comment: I am honoured. Thank you so much. Me happy :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: Will be proud to wear the shirt and equip the bottles. I'm with zenbike, though. Two bottles would be amazing, since it prevents a mismatch.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I even did not expec this, considering that I have not been too active, except for one period at the start. This makes me want to go back and look for some questions to answer :)

Comment: so rad!  thanks!

Comment: @zenbike Yeah, we'll do a pair of water bottles. :)

Comment: @AdamLear That's fantastic. Thanks so much for everything you do around the SE network!

Comment: Utterly awesome @Adam - :-)

Comment: @adam.  This is really appreciated. :)

Comment: Wearing the t-shirt right now. :)

Comment: I've been getting compliments on the shirt. It's awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: The shirt instantly attracts attention - enough detail that people want to find out what it is, and then have to ask - definite win!

Comment: Cool swag, Thanks SE! Especially the bottles, I'm always in need of new ones.

Comment: There used to be a swag store, but its gone away.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store

Answer (score 4):

Is this a regular thing?  Can we have it again please?

Comment: answering to bump the thread in Meta, cos adding a comment doesn't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I was under the assumption that this was a sort of "graduation present" when the site hit a certain size. It hasn't happened again since they did it that first time.

Comment: Crap. Love swag.

Comment: @adamlear what would it take to do this again?  Cash ?

Comment: The main cost is the postage; it's more than the cost of the stuff. And if they did for us then they'd have to do it for all sites. Prohibitive.